# Can only one foreign key reference a primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys, data-modeling

When creating a table and a database in do the foreign keys need to be unique?

For example

Table: **Manifest**

```
Manifest_Barcode - PK
Vehicle_reg - FK
weight
description
```

Table: **Vehicle**

```
vechicle_reg - PK
employee_ID - FK
make
model
```

Table: **Drivers**

```
employee_ID - PK
vechicle_reg - FK
name
adress
phone_Number
year
```

Or, can I use the same foreign key in 2 different tables? Like the above?

Comment: Yes you can have same foreign key multiple tables and intact it will make your schema rather clear to read and connect. Please check [this post out ]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349988/same-foreign-key-in-multiple-tables)

Comment: Can you please do 3 things. 1) Stop tagging your questions SQL Developer unless your question is specifically related to the functionality of that program. The database you are using is not SQL Developer it's Oracle. Please use that tag. 2) At least make an attempt to spell words correctly, it would be polite. 3) Come up with better titles. They're how people come to your question and _"sql developer forgeion key"_ is not a good title or even an indication of what your actual problem is.

Comment: This is actually a redundant post and doesn't show he has put minimum effort.

Comment: @bonCodigo, your duplicate isn't a duplicate. It's MySQL specific (however relevant). If you can find a duplicate that is related to Oracle of the ANSI standard then please do so and flag the post as such. I can't at the moment making this a relevant and useful question.

Comment: @bonCodigo I'm sorry that i have made the post badly, i don't visit forums or things like these often, ill try better in the future,
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely appropriate and quite normal to have multiple FOREIGN KEYs that refer to the same PRIMARY KEY.  They are not the *same* FOREIGN KEY (they will each build a separate index to use in enforcing the key), they are different FOREIGN KEYs with similar definitions.

Note that you will have to create the table `vehicle1` before declaring either of the FOREIGN KEYs.